# Best practices to apply in Domain Driven Design principles?

Tags: domain-driven-design, uml

[image: Sample UML diagram]
Domain Driven Design can be really confusing at times and since I am rather new to this technique I would like to have some answers regarding those scenarios that are currently bugging me.

Here a simple diagram to represent my question using DDD principles. My question is about aggregate roots, domain validation and "ways to do" or best practices.

1. In this scenario, how would you implement a way to count the number of comments written by a user? Would it be a method in "Review"? Or would it be best to be a method in a repository (ReviewRepository)?
2. How do I make other entities access comments if they need to? Having this scenario, does that mean that Comment isn't part anymore of the "Review" aggregates?
3. What if comment have a composition relationship with some other entity? How would you manage the access to that entity? Is comment responsible of this entity or the root?
4. Any other suggestions or facts regarding this model? Any best practices I should fellow when designing a model?

Thanks.

**NOTE: The answer must fellow DDD principles**

There a little error in the Review entity. "Compte" in the Add method is "Account" and should be A instead of C.

Comment: "The answer must fellow DDD principles"  Does that mean this is homework?

Comment: Haha. Not at all. I just want an answer from someone that actually know about DDD. If this was an homework i wouldn't came here, i would simply ask my teacher. I actually did the diagram and working on this simple application to understand some underlying concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this scenario, how would you implement a way to count the number of comments written by an user ?

Responsibility belongs with review.  It's an aggregate of comments.  Count is a first-class feature of any aggregate.

> How do i make others entities access comments if they need to ?

Comments are accessible via a Review.  A Review is an aggregate of comments.

> What if comment have a composition relationship with some other entity ?

"What if" questions are hard to answer without a concrete and specific example.  After all, the design is driven by the problem domain, not random thoughts.

If some "other" entity also appears to be a composition of Comments, you have to go back to the domain experts and try to determine where the **real** responsibility lies.

One pair of question is "if the review is removed, what happens to the comments?"  and "If the mysterious 'other' is removed, what happens to the comments?"  This can help find the responsibilities.